# Does pywin32 install cause any changes to registry settings that could affect MAPI

Tags: pywin32, python-2.4

I recently installed pywin32 at a client site and after this occurred, they started experiencing MAPI errors. I cannot see how the install would have had any effect on their emails. pywin32 was simply installed with no errors. I am a novice with Python so I apologise if there is not enough detail or for the lack of understanding on my part.
Pywin32 was installed on remote desktop and the error they were receiving around this time was "241938E error - can't open default message store (MAPI)". The actual python script using win32.com makes no use of MAPI (simply used for word application tasks) and worked without any issues.
The IT firm for the client wants to know if pywin32 causes any changes to registry settings that could have impacted them and caused this error? Incidentally, they had an office365 change around the same time. I think the 'finger pointing' is more in that direction but I do need to rule out any related registry setting changes that pywin32 may make on install that could have caused or contributed to the problem they were experiencing.

Comment: SOLVED: Problem found to be a Microsoft error - reported April 27.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: Problem found to be a Microsoft error - reported April 27